# In vim editor, curly braces are acting weird

Tags: vim

my editor was working fine till yesterday. But I don't know why it is acting weird, maybe its because I press some keys or something. Whenever I open curly braces, it shows as it used to. But when I close the curly brace they looks highlighted in yellow color and my function goes in loop. I don't know how to fix this. Please give your suggestions as soon as possible. Thank You.

[image]

Comment: What does command grep DoMatchParen .vimrc reveal?

Comment: I wrote this command     [root@srvmum06crmph01 Users]# grep DoMatchParen .vimrc .....got this....
grep: .vimrc: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you press <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>}</kbd> to search `}` by accident. Try this command:

```
:noh
```

It'll cancel the highlighting.

Comment: well i am not trying to search anything....I want the highlighed close curly brace to be a normal close curly brace...like the above open curly brace is not highlighted and it has color something violet.....till yesterday, the close curly brace is also of color violet and wasn't highlighted..but today now I press some keys on my keyboard and starts acting weird and whole file is not working as it should be.....I think i made my problem clear to you all....please help me soon.

Comment: @santabanta: He did not suggest you to search something. He meant that maybe you did search for `}` (by pressing `/}<CR>`, or `#` or `*` while on a `}`), and that the highlighting is active. Try to execute `:noh` to remove search highlighting, and if it doesn't work you've eliminated one possible source of your problem, if it does work you've eliminated the problem.

Comment: sorry man, I couldn't understand that first....but this works man....thank you kev and Amadan......May god bless you all....thank you once again.